# Sharepoint large list filtering

Tags: 2010, filter, large-lists, indexed-column

Currently in Sharepiont 2010.
I have a list that just went over 5000 items.  I have columns indexed and all views are filtered with these indexed columns.  One of the columns is a "Date and Time" type called Recommendation Date.  My hope is to use a filter showing the last 12 months' info, so filtering this date to showing everything with a Recommendation Date greater than or equal to [Today]-365.

If I have [Today]-365 it says my list is too large.  Playing with the numbers, at Recommendation Date greater than or equal to [Today]-282, I have 1722 items returned.  At greater than or equal to [Today]-283 it says I have too many.  At exactly (equals) [Today]-283, it returns 10 items.  My [Today]-365 should be far less than 5000 items (it's taken 3 years to get to this point), any thoughts as to what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Getting the views to work on large items can be tricky. Maybe the view is using some column that is not indexed? In certain cases I used this hack: Try to add to your view another clause where ID>1 .That helped me in quite few situations.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried ID>1 and that didn't work.  All filters are with indexed columns.  Now that we are one day past my question, [Today]-283 works, but [Today]-284 is tripping the "too many items."  So there's something wrong with an item (or items) with a date code of 13 July 2018!